# How to get a JSON object and map it into object in spring 3.0 controller using POST method?

Tags: json, spring, http, post

I want to add request mapping my controller which gets a Json of Array of an object.
The JSON will be sent from javascript using post.

Thanks,
Kfir

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Spring's `@RequestBody` annotation, e.g.

```
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> handleJsonPost(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestJson) {
   ...
   return responseJson;
}
```

This will also send the return value back as JSON.

You'll also need to include the Jackson library in your application's classpath, and add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

to your context (see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven))